# Swift: Is it a good idea to use enum's raw value to access a UIButton and a string from a constant array?

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, uibutton, constants

I apologize in advance, this is hard to explain. I will provide more detail if needed.

This is the Constants struct that I use to reference `UIButtons` in a collection array and use as keys for dictionaries.

```
struct Constants {
    static let scoreA = "score_a"
    static let scoreB = "score_b"
    static let scoreC = "score_c"
    static let scoreD = "score_d"


    static let constantsArray = [kScoreA, kScoreB, kScoreC, kScoreD]
    enum Scores: Int, CaseIterable { case scoreA = 1, ScoreB, ScoreC, ScoreD}
}
```

My initial view controller has a lot of `UIButtons`. All the score UIButtons are tagged from 1 and up. The `UIButtons` are hooked to an IBOutlet UIButton array. This way I can avoid having too many IBOutlets

```
@IBOutlet var collectionOfScoreButtons: Array<UIButton>!
```

I reference the UIButtons using code like this throughout my App.

```
if let scoreAButton = collectionOfScoreButtons[Constants.Scores.scoreA.rawValue - 1]
```

The UIButtons order is the same as the enum's order e.g. scoreA is the first item in the enum and scoreA button is the first button in the array.

And I can retrieve a dictionary key like this, so I can update its value

```
// after pushing a score button
func handleScoreValue(tag: Int) {
     let scoreKey = Constants.constantScoreArray[tag - 1]
     dictionary[scoreKey, default: 0] += 1
}
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to handle this situation. The code works well, but I feel like there is a better way.

Comment: I would recommend against using tags, in almost all circumstances. Instead, make a subclass of `UIButton`, and add the necessary identifying information (enum values, delegate, whatever.) Don't fiddle with raw integer values, you're just begging for bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any advantage of using `Scores` `enum` to get reference for certain button, you have to specify index anyway

```
if let scoreAButton = collectionOfScoreButtons[0]
```

also you can make your `Constants` `enum` and implement `CaseIterable` protocol which allows you to make array of all `enum`'s cases using `Enum.allCases`

```
enum Score: String, CaseIterable {
    case A = "score_a"
    case B = "score_b"
    case C = "score_c"
    case D = "score_d"
}
```

then I believe you have IBAction for your button so you can get index of `sender` in your array of buttons. Then you don't have to set `tag` of `UIButton`

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let index = collectionOfScoreButtons.index(of: sender) {
        handleScoreValue(index: index)
    }
}
```

Finally you can get `scoreKey` as `rawValue` of case for certain index in `allCases` array

```
func handleScoreValue(index: Int) {
    let scoreKey = Score.allCases[index].rawValue
    dictionary[scoreKey, default: 0] += 1
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Also, I feel like I am being spoiled here with your insight of not setting tags. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an `enum` directly ?

```
enum Constants: String, CaseIterable {
    case scoreA = "score_a"
    case scoreB = "score_b"
    case scoreC = "score_c"
    case scoreD = "score_d"
}
```

So you can loop through your enum cases like

```
Constants.allCases[anyIndex].rawValue
```

Comment: Let me give that a try. That looks like it should work.